# Java - parseInt()

Tags: java, android

```
public void OK(View v)
{
    EditText editTextView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextView);
    String myEditValue = editTextView.getText().toString();
    int equação = Integer.parseInt(myEditValue);
    editTextView.setText(equação + "CERTO!");}
```

Dá erro quando existem caracteres do tipo "(" ou "+" etc. Existe alguma forma de os reconhecer?

Comment: Vc está dizendo que dá erro dentro do setText?

Comment: O erro é esse `;` ai depois que fecha o parênteses, não precisa dele

Comment: Tem que ficar assim `editTextView.setText(equação + "CERTO!") `

Comment: Amigo o erro ocorre porque se ter um ( ou então + ou qualquer outro caracter não reconhecerá como um inteiro, na conversão

Comment: Anderson Henrique , há então alguma maneira de reconhecer por exemplo isto " (6*2)+7+5 " tudo como um int ?

Comment: Não. Tem de fazer split e parse de de cada parcela individualmente e fazer as operações entre cada coisa. Ou utilizar uma biblioteca para o efeito

Comment: Você está tentando implementar uma "Calculadora de String". Isto não é suportado diretamente pela linguagem e, como o Isac disse, você terá de efetuar todo o parsing da String manualmente e, após, efetuar os cálculos, considerando precedência de operadores e etc. Você pode procurar algo pronto ou pesquisar tutoriais na Internet, já que este é um 'exercício' comum.

Comment: Vou tentar procurar a ver se consigo o efeito que desejo. Eu inicialmente achei que era bastante simples, bastava o parsing de toda a string, mas depois deparei me com esse erro. No resto do meu código existe uma série de equações que utilizam esses caracteres e não tive problema nenhum, isto porque sempre trabalhei com int's. Assim ou arranjo outro método pra obter as equações ou tenho q fazer como vocês disseram.
Vou experimentar a ver 
Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ache isso no fórum, e achei interessante!
Não sei se vai funcionar, mas não custa você tentar aí!

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;    

ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String infix = "3+2*(4+5)";
System.out.println(engine.eval(infix));
```

Espero que ajude! :D

[Link da solução](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662001/java-string-to-math-equation)

Comment: @Eduardo Brito, apenas tome cuidado onde vai usar isso, pois é extremamente inseguro. Ele pode executar também qualquer função que o Java consiga, como ler e escrever em arquivos na máquina.

Comment: Eu simplesmente não consigo importar... Mas penso que essa seria mesmo a solução

Answer (score 0):

Há três formas bem simples de resolver:

1) Adicione o atributo abaixo em seu EditText e evite caracteres indesejados:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

2) Utilize os métodos da própria classe String:

```
EditText editTextView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextView);
String myEditValue = editTextView.getText().toString();

//Removendo caracteres indesejados
myEditValue.replace("(", "");
myEditValue.replace("+", "");

int equação = Integer.parseInt(myEditValue);
editTextView.setText(equação + "CERTO!");
```

3) Pesquise um pouco sobre Regex, que é uma String utilizada para validar outras Strings e se o usuário inserir um caractere indesejado, mostre uma mensagem a ele. Existe o método da classe String `mEditValue.replaceAll(String regex, String substituta)`, que com o Regex evita que você use o passo 2 para todos os casos.

Boa Sorte.

Comment: isto não vai funcionar simplesmente  :/ mas obrigado pela ajuda na mesma